# Unable to do nmap UDP scan using Robot frame

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, nmap

I am trying to scan on systems using Nmap and Robot Framework. If I use TCP scan it works but TCP scanning does not work with Robot Framework. I used the **Run Process** function to execute the Nmap command on a Linux machine.

`Scan Host
  [Documentation]  Will do Nmap scan
  [Arguments]  ${SERIAL_NUMBER}  ${WIRELESS_AP}  ${HOST_IP}
  ${result} =  Run Process  nmap -vvvv -sU -T3 -Pn ${PORTS} ${HOST_IP}  shell=yes
  Log To Console  ${result.stdout}`

The following code works and the difference only is replacing **-sU** to **-sT**

```
Scan Host
  [Documentation]  Will do Nmap scan
  [Arguments]  ${SERIAL_NUMBER}  ${WIRELESS_AP}  ${HOST_IP}
  ${result} =  Run Process  nmap -vvvv -sT -T3 -Pn ${PORTS} ${HOST_IP}  shell=yes
  Log To Console  ${result.stdout}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: UDP Scanning requires root access  and if you are running as normal user without root access, -sU will fail.   https://www.infosecmatter.com/why-does-nmap-need-root-privileges/